# How to resize UITableView in Today Extension

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uitableview, swift

I am building a Today Extension for both iPhone and iPad and I am having the problem that I am not able to use different Storyboards for iPad and iPhone.

I am able to resize the width of the Extensions view with

```
if isIpad() {
    width = 550
} else {
    width = 275
}
preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(width, 200)
```

but I am not able to resize the tableViews Frame with this code

```
tableView.frame = view.frame
```

after the code above.

Does anyone know how to make a universal Today Extension?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a UITableViewController or you can use autoLayout to pin the tableView to the container. In both cases the width will be adjusted automatically.

For the height of the widget use something like this: (self.rows should be NSArray containing the rows)

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (self.rows) {
        CGSize size = self.preferredContentSize;
        size.height = self.rows.count * 44.0f;
        self.preferredContentSize = size;

        return self.rows.count;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I am using a UITableViewController now. This did the trick:) And to automatically resize the content size to fit the tableView I am using `preferredContentSize = tableView.contentSize`

Comment: Is there a way that this can take into account Self-Sizing Cells and Dynamic Type?